# How can we check our IP Address without making any connection to server?

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, rest

I know connection required for getting information from server.
and through webRTC stun ping help us to check out local & private ip addresses.

**Is there any way to get ip address with server ping or stun request?**

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript code to get Ip

```
//get the IP addresses associated with an account
function getIPs(callback){
    var ip_dups = {};

    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

    //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
    if(!RTCPeerConnection){
        //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
        //
        //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
        //<script>...getIPs called in here...
        //
        var win = iframe.contentWindow;
        RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
            || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
            || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    }

    //minimal requirements for data connection
    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
    };

    var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

    //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

    function handleCandidate(candidate){
        //match just the IP address
        var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
        var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

        //remove duplicates
        if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
            callback(ip_addr);

        ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
    }

    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

        //skip non-candidate events
        if(ice.candidate)
            handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
    };

    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    //create an offer sdp
    pc.createOffer(function(result){

        //trigger the stun server request
        pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

    }, function(){});

    //wait for a while to let everything done
    setTimeout(function(){
        //read candidate info from local description
        var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

        lines.forEach(function(line){
            if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                handleCandidate(line);
        });
    }, 1000);
}

//Test: Print the IP addresses into the console
getIPs(function(ip){console.log(ip);});
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP headers in a request will have source ip in it. And the system who received the requests, in your case the ipinfo.io, can check for this and send back the IP of the caller easily.

But, it seems ipinfo.io is only detecting your outbound server's ip address. That is, if you are behind a LAN or a Proxy Server, ipinfo.io detects only that IP address not your actual system's ip. For this, HTTP header `X-Forwarded-For` is to be used.